# react-testing-library input change test always passing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I noticed that if I broke my form by hard coding a value to the input field, and not having any onChange - my tests were still passing!

I tried using userEvent as well, but the test is still passing fine. 
What am I doing wrong here? In the browser I obviously can't change the value at all, it's stuck to the hardcoded value.

I have created a sandbox showing the issue as well: https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-wave-hlsfp

React Component:

```
import React from "react";

const RegisterFormExample = () => (
  <form>
    <label htmlFor="name">Full name</label>
    <input type="name" id="name" value="this does not break a test" />
  </form>
);

export default RegisterFormExample;
```

Jest test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import RegisterForm from "components/RegisterFormExample";

describe("RegisterForm", () => {
  test("full name input", async () => {
    const { getByLabelText } = render(<RegisterForm />);
    const input = getByLabelText(/full name/i);
    //This passes
    fireEvent.change(input, {
      target: {
        value: "Test Example",
      },
    });
    expect(input).toHaveValue("Test Example");

    //This is passing too
    await userEvent.type(input, "Test Example");
    expect(input).toHaveValue("Test Example");
  });
});
```

Comment: From what it looks like, in your test you are setting the value to "Test Example" and then expecting it to have a value of "Test Example", so of-course it passes.

Comment: @George - try the form in the browser in the sandbox, it won't work because there's a hardcoded value set.

Comment: test failed for me when i changed the Test Example string. what browser are you using? Some browsers might not be able to programatically fire events (even if its possible to set the input value). And anyway, the test makes no sense. You are only testing that the fireEvent.change works, nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on my Github issue [here](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/528) from eps1lon.
Turns out that setting a wrong type on the input field can mess up the test and make it pass, never would have guessed that.

By setting type to `text` instead of `name`, the test fails as expected.

```
<input type="text" id="name" value="test" />
```